# I can't see logs from deployed apps on Payara 4.1, just |#] on Netbeans console tab

Tags: logging, log4j2, payara, netbeans-11

I can't see logs (log4j2) generated by apps deployed **in the Netbeans console**, I changed a few logs to `System.out.print` or `java.util.logging.Logger` so I can see them

```
`|#]
|#]
|#]
|#]`
```

I tried to restore some files on domain/domain1/config, like domain.xml, logging.properties but the issue persists.

Here is a larger piece of the console (of Netbeans 11), in the log files of Payara I can see all the logs, from all levels, the problem is on Netbeans console
`

```
=================================================================
Vaadin is running in DEBUG MODE.
Add productionMode=true to web.xml to disable debug features.
To show debug window, add ?debug to your application URL.
=================================================================|#]
|#]
|#]
|#]
|#]
  EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier|#]
  /file:/D:/NetBeansProjects/Traslado/target/Traslado-1/WEB-INF/classes/_trasladoPU login successful|#]
|#]
|#]
  Listening to REST requests at context: /management/domain.|#]
  Redirecting to /index.jsf|#]
  Admin Console: Initializing Session Attributes...|#]
  Payara Health Check Service is shutdown.|#]
```

`

logging.properties

```
#GlassFish logging.properties list
#Tue Aug 27 14:14:03 ART 2019
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.level=INFO
org.eclipse.persistence.session.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.container.cmp.level=INFO
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=1
org.glassfish.naming.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.jta.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.jdo.level=INFO
javax.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.SyslogHandler.useSystemLogging=false
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.logtoConsole=false
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.managedbean.level=INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter
javax.enterprise.system.core.config.level=INFO
javax.org.glassfish.persistence.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.level=INFO
org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.level=INFO
ShoalLogger.level=CONFIG
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=50000
javax.enterprise.system.container.web.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.javamail.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.core.classloading.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.webservices.registry.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.corba.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.core.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.taglib.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.maxHistoryFiles=0
javax.enterprise.system.webservices.saaj.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.excludeFields=
javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.file=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/server.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=%h/java%u.log
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationOnDateChange=false
org.glassfish.admingui.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.sqltrace.level=FINE
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.formatter=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
javax.enterprise.system.core.selfmanagement.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.jms.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.core.security.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.multiLineMode=true
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.level=ALL
javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.mdb.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.level=INFO
org.apache.coyote.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.timing.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.compressOnRotation=false
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.validator.util.Version=warn
javax.mail.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.ssl.security.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context.level=INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINEST
handlerServices=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler,com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.SyslogHandler
javax.enterprise.system.util.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.resource.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationTimelimitInMinutes=0
org.apache.jasper.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.dol.level=WARNING
javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.level=INFO
org.apache.catalina.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.tools.backup.level=INFO
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationLimitInBytes=2000000
.level=INFO
javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common.level=WARNING
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.SyslogHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.XMLFormatter
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.retainErrorsStasticsForHours=0
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.flushFrequency=1
javax.enterprise.system.webservices.rpc.level=INFO
```

**Update**: I changed to the other domain "payaradomain" didn't work, creating another clean domain neither

**2nd update**: reinstalling the IDE (removing cache, not importing config) didn't work

There is an open issue unfixed yet
[jira-report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-3042)

Comment: happened to me too from version 11.0 to 11.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

downgraded to Netbeans 11.0 and solved

Answer (score 0):

(sorry, too low rep to comment)

Can you maybe post your logging.properties configuration?

Did you try to create a new domain and test again? I mean when you already replaced domain.xml and logging.properties then what keeps you from creating a new domain?

Comment: Did you check your log4j2 config then? Maybe you forgot to add an appender for console?

Comment: log4j2.xml is part of the project (under Git) and hasn't changed in the last 2 years and the issue is not related to one project, all projects have it, I work on W10, my colleges use Linux and they don't have this problem, 2 months ago we moved from Netbeans 8.2 to 11.1, I didn't have this problem in the beginning but after changing some configs on Payara, it started

Comment: Hmm, unless you remember what those "some configs" are I guess it is hard to tell. Only thing that comes to my mind when hearing that it works under Linux is that maybe you changed some directories which have special characters or spaces in them?

Comment: Or are you maybe by chance using slash separators instead of backslash for files? Or can Windows nowadays cope with this? E.g. in your logging.properties there also is a file name with slashes. But Java probably does the magic and it works under Windows with slashes anyway.

Comment: in the `server.log` files created by Payara, everything is there, every log, no single one is missing, the problem is the Netbeans' console or in between, I can't figure out why it comes out empty :@

Comment: I just learned that java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler logs to System.err (not System.out). Could you check what happens when you replace your System.out.println calls by System.err.println? Moreover, maybe the Netbeans console suppresses error output for some strange reason?