# Logs are not showing in Netbeans console after version 11.0

Tags: logging, jakarta-ee, netbeans, logback, payara

My JakartaEE 8 application was used to show logs in the Netbeans console when I was using version 11.0. When I upgraded to version 11.1, 11.2 and recently 11.3, I still don't see the application log in the Netbeans console.

I tried modifying my logback config but I'm not quite good actually with this, so I stuck with default configuration. I tried reverting to Netbeans 11.0 and the logs were showing in the console. I read somewhere that Netbeans 11.1 broke something about the console logging, but I can remind where I saw that. Any idea?

**Environnement:**

- Apache Netbeans 11.3
- Payara Server 5.201
- JakarteEE 8.0
- Logback

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg</Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="ca.allaxis" level="ALL" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</logger>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
```

**Example**

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InspectionController.class);
LOGGER.info("Create registration(s) for {} selected inspections.", selectedItems.size());
```

Comment: [1] Is this open and unresolved NetBeans bug report relevant for your problem?... [NETBEANS-3042 can't see loggers (log4j2) created from apps deployed on Payara servers](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-3042). It states that _"it is a Netbeans issue introduced in 11.1 version + payara 5"_ which corresponds to what you are describing. [2] See also [I can't see logs from apps on Payara 4.1, just # on Netbeans console tab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57679272/2985643) where the "solution" was to regress back to NetBeans 11.0.

Comment: i have similar error so i am using Netbeans 8 for now

Comment: Yes, this describe the problem I have with Netbeans 11.1+. But reverting to Netbeans 11.0 is not a solution. This needs to be solved or have a hack. What's the point of breaking the console like this.

Comment: @PierreFrancisRoy You say _"reverting to Netbeans 11.0 is not a solution"_, and that is true (since it is only a workaround), but it is a viable option for most users. What real world issue(s) do you have to face if you revert to NetBeans 11.0? The only significant limitation I can think of is that you lose the ability to use JDK 13 or JDK 14, and that is unlikely to be a major problem for most users.

Comment: @skomisa I can live with Netbeans 11.0. I still feel that the last two years were frustrating in the Java world as no combination of tools were working to allow me to upgrade while keeping the same level of productivity. Ideally I should have stayed with JDK8 + Netbeans 8.2 + Java EE 7/8 and Payara 4.x. As soon as I started to upgrade one or the other it started to break my tool chain, either Netbeans didn't supported the latest Payara, either there was issue with a more recent JDK, either I lost the console, or hot deploy. I don't like to see regression in Netbeans which make it useless.

Comment: Fully understood. NetBeans 12.0 will be released shortly and I see no sign that the issue will be fixed in that release either. A comment for the bug report 3042 that I linked to is _"the problem is still present in 11.2 and Payara 5.194, **but with 4.1.x logs works fine**"_ so one possibility might be that you could upgrade NetBeans and regress Payara. I'm certainly not saying that's _good_, but merely raising it as a possible approach.

Comment: @skmosi Thank you. This is an option if I revert from JakartaEE 8 to JavaEE 8 and maybe some other minor tweats I made when I did the upgrade. How can I influence the correction of this bug, what can I do?

Comment: You can [add comments to the existing bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-3042), detailing your specific problems, and stress its importance to your company. Note that another user who was not involved in reporting the bug has already done that. You will have to register first, but that is a trivial process: click Login in the top right of the screen then click the _Sign up_ link. Good luck.

Comment: @skomisa Thank you so much!

Comment: This issue and several others issues have forced me to use Netbeans 8.2 still. Hope Netbeans will gain its previous glory.

Answer (score 0):

If change the time format in pattern to HH;mm:ss.SSS the log shown in NetBeans (I use 11.1 and 12.3, works too). Because, I use specific pattern for console and for log file.

**log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration monitorInterval="30">
  <properties>
    <property name="name">server-log</property>
    <property name="path">d:/server/logs</property>
    <property name="pattern">%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</property>
    <property name="pattern2">%d{HH;mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] [%t] %c{1} - %msg</property>
  </properties>
  <appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern2}" charset="UTF-8"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${path}/${name}.log"
                 filePattern="${path}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/${name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>${pattern}</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy /><!-- Rotated everyday -->
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB"/> <!-- Or every 5 MB -->
      </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
  </appenders>
  <loggers>
    <root level="info"> <!-- We log everything -->
      <appender-ref ref="Console"/> <!-- To console -->
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/> <!-- And to a rotated file -->
    </root>
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```